# value of variable after many post or pre increments

Tags: c, post-increment

I am almost new to programming.

I see a lot of questions of this type in many question papers and exams

```
int j= 5;
int i=0;
i= j++ + ++j + j++ - ++j ;
```

I always predict the wrong value of variable 'i'. My friends suggested many approaches
but all fails in some or the other such expression.

Is there some universal rule/approach to evaluate such type of expressions?

Comment: Duplicate of many questions.  Undefined behaviour; there is no right or wrong answer for the result.

Comment: Read [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior)

Comment: The universal rule is 'if a variable has its value modified more than once between sequence points, then the behaviour is undefined'.  There are other ways to get undefined behaviour (`a[i++] = i;`, for example), but that covers this case.

Comment: Wikipedia page [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior][1] says that "ANSI C standard chose to leave similar constructions undefined"


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI C explicitly refuses to make any guarantees about the order of argument evaluation for a n-ary operation. Therefore having

```
y = j++ + ++j
```

..you might end up with a logical equivalent of one of the following:

```
x1 = j++; x2 = ++j; y = x1 + x2
```

..or

```
x1 = ++j; x2 = j++; y = x1 + x2
```

depending on compiler, compiler version, OS, and even compilation flags. More complex expressions make things progressively more messy.